# Multiple animations in framer issue

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

I would like to add a reveal effect to an element and then use parallax on it. The problem is that the initial position has changed by 50px, so the reveal animation happens, and then when I start to scroll, it does move with parallax effect, but it jumps back to 0, then it starts to move.
How can I avoid that jump? How can I start the parallax effect from 50?

Note: parallax is optional in my example

```
import { motion, useScroll, useTransform } from 'framer-motion';

function AnimationWrapper({ children, delay = 0, parallax = false, speed = 3 }) {
    // Convert the first child to a motion component if it's a valid element
    const MotionComponent = children && typeof children === 'object' && children.type ? motion(children.type) : motion.div; // Fallback to motion.div

    const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll();
    const transform = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0, 100 * speed]);

    return (
        <MotionComponent
            viewport={{ once: true }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 50 }}
            whileInView={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 1, delay: delay }}
            {...parallax == true && {style: { y: transform }}}
            {...children.props}
        >
            {children.props.children}
        </MotionComponent>
    );
}

export default AnimationWrapper;
```

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?